# Confused in my choice between (webOS, BADA and Iphone) vs Android

Tags: android, security, platform, mobile-application

So I was doing this comparative study between the application security model between android and now I need a benchmark for it to compete against. The problem though is I am pretty new to mobile application development and barely know the names and probably used a phone or two in the process with each of the OSes. Now the dilemma I am in is, which OS should I pitt against the Andorid to compete with for a security model study. At most I can pick two because I literally will not have the time to complete developing applications for all the Operating Systems in the market to do a comparative study.

Which one would be the best choices according to you? (Please elaborate as to why its a worthy competitor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use too many exclamation point in your question!  So I will sound very angry as I answer you!

A good choice against which to compare Android would be Symbian!  Because Symbian is an operating system designed to be secure!  It requires application signing!  But Symbian is significantly older!  So you should probably also pick a newer phone OS!  iOS, WebOS, Windows Mobile, and Maemo are the only real new competitors to Android!  But Maemo is probably a poor choice, as it is effectively just a Linux distribution for phones and is current only deployed on the Nokia N900!

So, my recommendation would be to choose WebOS or the iPhone OS and Symbian!!!

Comment: Lol! thanks... I am a very up about this so the "!". Also till now I have hardly got any responses to some very important questions I have even for the android developers google groups. So even more!

Comment: What about win mobile 7? Is do you have any idea regarding the nature of the os? Also could you direct me to some material that could help me with my study on webOS. I have been pondering over it for a while now, and I think it could be pitted against android. Far too many studies have been done on IOS, so I am not so interested in it. Also because I would have to purchase the SDK, I am not a big fan. :P
Also any special reason to sideline bada? (now I might have a litle too many "?" =D)

Comment: @ Shouvik You don't have to buy the SDK from Apple to use it. You just need to register as an Apple Developer, and its for free. When you want to upload an application to the App Store or test your app on a real device - then you pay 99 USD, but not before. BR -

Comment: +1 for exclamation marks! I piss off whenever they are used excessively.

Answer (score 1):

If you would only compare to one other Mobile OS, my suggestion would be iOS (iPhone OS) rather than Symbian. They are in a conceptual level fairly similar to each other, and they target the same audience.

The second choice would be Research in Motion (RIM/Blackberry), which was the preferred choice for business people for many years becoming a symbol of status.

If you have the time to do a wider study I think you could compare Android, iOS, RIM, Windows Mobile and Symbian. I'd really like to read that study :-)

Good Luck on your upcoming study.

Comment: He he, I actually find your idea very intriguing! :P I never actually considered the blackberry perspective. Ideally it makes a lot of sense because RIM does give the highest priority to security. I don't know much about Win7 mobile but going by their track record we can make a considerably safe bet, it would not stand a chance against the likes of BB, android or ios =). symbian I never thought about. Actually I thought symbian was pretty much out of the gave when nokia decided to go linux..

Comment: Its actually my masters thesis, so have to draw a line on how many I am going to study on. Back in uni they drill you pretty hard on all the aspects of the platform not just your domain. But if i have time I would definitely do a study on all. As of now android is hapless in the domain on documentation of its permissions. It needs to do a lot of work there is they want their users to be aware of what they do when they grant an application the permissions it requests for.